# Powering and operating dual electric linear actuators

Tags: power-supply, voltage, relay, amperage, actuator

I am in the process of building a height-adjusting desk. I am pretty good with computers (I'm a programmer), but I never learned much in the way of electrical engineering.

I recently purchased two Eco-Worthy brand linear actuators. They each have an 18-inch stroke and a 320 lbs. static load bearing capability. They just have two wires, the positive and the negative wires. They are supposed to operated at 12 volts with a 1 amp minimum and 3 amp maximum.

I intend to operate them both at the same time in the same direction. So what I am unsure of is primarily the power source. My understanding is that I would still use a 12 volt power supply to power both at the same time.

But will I need it to have a 3 amp output or more than that? Will the amperage be reduced as it is divided among devices? Am I misunderstanding how this should work?

Also, if I get a momentary rocker switch will I wire both together and then to the switch? Should I get a relay to run this through? Any recommendations on how I hookup the A/C power to it? Since it won't have any plug inputs.

Here is a [link](http://www.eco-worthy.com/catalog/worthy-18450mm-stoke-linear-actuator-1500n-57mms-p-337.html) to the info about the actuators I purchased. Any help in figuring out the electrical setup is welcome.

Comment: Dont attach the actuators directly to the desk, you'll tear the slides or guides or whatever you use on the rising legs right off. Use an actuator bracket and a 2"x3" piece of plywood to make a platform on the rising part of actuator but leave an 1/4" gap between the bottom of desk and actuator platform (where the actuator comes to full rest). You'll have to take care when designing the legs of the desk and positioning the actuators relative to where things come to rest. HINT: Dont allow slides to be fully retracted when actuator is fully retracted, leave a bit of a buffer to ensure no stress

Comment: I attached the actuators to mounting brackets which mount onto the wood directly. Though that point is double thickness to provide further strength.

Comment: And it has worked fine for a year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to buy a switching power supply with a 12V output capable of at least 6A if you want to be able to operate both struts at the same time under full load.  The amount of current drawn will depend on how much force is pushing against each strut.  If you only need to operate one strut at once, then a 3A supply will probably do.

You could, in the simplest case, wire them directly in parallel.  However, it is unlikely that they will move synchronously unless they are directly bolted together, e.g. if there's one at each end of the desk they may become misaligned and jam or break the desk.  If one is under more load, it will move a little slower.  So probably you want a separate switch for each strut so that they can be controlled individually.

You will also need some means of reversing the polarity in order to change the direction of travel.  The usual means is a DPDT switch or relay; you can google up a schematic pretty easily.

If you buy switches rated for at least 3A (one strut) or 6A (both struts) then those switches can directly control the motor current.  More likely is that you might buy smaller/cheaper switches which actuate the coils of large (10A) relays, which are responsible for enabling and reversing the power.

Edit: you might want to look into building your desk so that it has a single central strut to perform the lifting work, supported by stabilising arms/scissors/whatever at each side of the desk.  That way, there are no alignment issues and no need to synchronise two struts.  If your lifting geometry results in more than 150kg load on the single strut, you could probably put the two right next to each other and they would be mechanically synced and provide up to 300kg of support together.

Comment: Ok, so I can go over the combined amperage just fine then. I do want both to move up and down at the same time (since this is for a desk). I was just going to put one on the left and one on the right.

Comment: I will read more about the DPDT switches tomorrow. That looks interesting and promising.

Answer (score 1):

Each device must meet specification; if you have 10 of these in parallel then you would need a 12V source capable of providing 3x10 Amps, or 30 Amps.

"Unit can be controlled with a double pole, double throw switch or with the built-in position sensor and optional linear actuator programmable controller."

It looks like you can control it with just a DPDT switch. Regarding the programmable controller inside, good luck getting the specifications to communicate with it as this isn't easy in my experience but you can contact the vendor and they should provide them to you. Some things to think about, are what happens when it gets to the end of its extension?

Comment: The way I see it is if both get to the end of their extensions (they have automatic limiters built-in) then it will essentially synchronize their positions. Full top and full bottom should equally have this effect.

Comment: Yes, they should resynchronize if you drive both of them to either end of their travel.  The only issue is that if you make a number of adjustments without going all the way to the end, they will tend to get out of sync because there will inevitably be a small difference in their speeds.  This might be due to differences in their internal friction or because you have something heavier on one side of the desk.  It's not a disaster, but something I would find very annoying if I bought a product that behaved this way.

Comment: I guess an alternative would be to do something similar to bicycle shock systems. I could have a heavy duty support spring on one side providing a decent amount of lift while putting an actuator on the other side to provide the controlled lift and lowering. But I think it will be ok as is. They are identical.